# SBT just loops in IntelliJ IDEA on SBT:Compile

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.2

Using Intellij IDEA 12.1.6 and SBT 0.13.0

I generated the hello-play with Activator and generated IDEA project.  If I compile using the SBT console it both compiles and runs fine.  If I create a run configuration with a Before launch: Run SBT Action 'compile' and launch, I just get the spinning Executing SBT Action and it never stops.  I finally close IDEA.

Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can have the explanatioin of why this won't be fixed:

https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/issues/66

Instead you may just kill SBT (a small skull icon on the left pane), this will remove all those "Executing SBT Action" processes.